# TypeScript compiler API: typeChecker.typeToString() vs. Playground tooltips

Tags: typescript

Example:

```
const red = Symbol('red');
const green = Symbol('green');
type TColor2 =
  | typeof red
  | typeof green
;
```

Getting a description for the type whose alias is `TColor2`:

1. Playground tooltip: `'typeof red | typeof green'`
2. Compiler API: `'TColor2'`
   Approach:

   ```
   // node is either ts.TypeAliasDeclaration or ts.TypeNode
   const type = typeChecker.getTypeAtLocation(node);
   const typeName = typeChecker.typeToString(type, node);
   ```

Is there a way to get the text of the Playground tooltip via the compiler API?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass `TypeFormatFlags.InTypeAlias` flag to `typeToString`:

```
typeChecker.typeToString(type, node, TypeFormatFlags.InTypeAlias);
```

Then it will print `typeof red | typeof green`